# $M=\left\{(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_p)\in G^p: g_1\cdot g_2\cdots g_p=e_G\right\}$ for a group $G$ of order $n$. $|M|=?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group of order $n$ and p is a prime divisor of $n$. Let
$$M=\left\{(g_1,g_2,\dots,g_p)\in G^p:g_1\cdot g_2\cdots g_p=e_G\right\}$$
How many elements does $M$ have?

I tried some kind of combinatorial construction but couldn't really get anything.

Comment: At present the problem seems really easy. Arbitrarily pick the first $p-1$ elements and set $g_p$ as the inverse of the product. Did you miss anything?

Comment: Seems to me like $|M|=|G|^{p-1}$, irrespective of any condition about $p$ dividing $|G|$...

Comment: @ Parcly Taxel that's what I tried but I wasn't sure if I wouldn't miss any elements like that.

Answer (score 3):

$p$ doesn't have to be a prime, or even divide $n$. Arbitrarily pick the first $p-1$ factors of the product – this is the widest possible selection, nothing is missed out. Then $g_p$ is the inverse of the product of all the previous factors. So $|M|=n^{p-1}$.